# Conditional replacing of column values in dataframe?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe and I want to replace some values in that column based on a condition. My dataframe looks like this

```
ID    customer_name   arrival_month    leaving_month
1524   ABC              201508           201605 
1185   XYZ              201701           201801
8456   IJK              201801           201902
```

I am trying a simple operation here. I want to change the values in leaving_month column by currentmonth value =201802 where leaving_month>201802.
I have tried by .loc and it gives the error below.

```
df.loc[(df['leaving_month'] > 201802)] = 201802
KeyError: 'leaving_month'
```

I have also tried np.where which also gives an error.

```
df['leaving_month']=np.where(df['leaving_month']>currentmonth, currentmonth)
KeyError: 'leaving_month'
```

I have also tried with brute looping

```
for o in range(len(df)):
            if(df.loc[o,'leaving_month']>currentmonth):
                df.loc[o,'leaving_month']=currentmonth
IndexingError: Too many indexers
```

Can someone please point me in the right direction or figure out what am I doing wrong or suggest a better solution? This is quite simple problem but somehow I am not getting through.

Comment: yeah  that was a typo in the post. not the actual code

Comment: `KeyError: 'leaving_month'` clearly says that `df` does NOT have `'leaving_month'` column. What is the output of `df.columns.tolist()`?

Comment: I don't get an error in your updated example. There is still a mistake though... see my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are replacing an entire row. Instead, set a specific column with the `.loc`. See the second indexer in the solution below.

```
df.loc[df['leaving_month'] > 201802, 'leaving_month'] = 201802
df
```

returns

```
     ID customer_name  arrival_month  leaving_month
0  1524           ABC         201508         201605
1  1185           XYZ         201701         201801
2  8456           IJK         201801         201802
```

You can read about DataFrame indexing in the [Pandas docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html).

Comment: thanks for your input @Alex. unfortunately, both mistakes that you pointed out are not in the actual code.. just typo while copy pasting here